# How put a file when the email is sent to user contact form 7

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

Suppose  to have a different file that I can be send when the user compiles the contact form. I have two solution:
1) Create different contact form for every file 
2) Create one contact form for all file and use some if to differenciate the conditions

I want implement the second solution is it possibile. Anyone can help me?

Comment: conditions depends on choices of the form ?

Comment: it depends from products. I dont' want create every contact form for every product, i want create one contact form for all files.

Answer (score 1):

you can set dynamically the attachements with this filter :

```
add_filter("wpcf7_contact_form_properties", function ($properties, $contact_form) {


    if (isset($properties["mail"]["attachments"])) {

        $properties["mail"]["attachments"] = "/var/products/file.pdf";

    }


    return $properties;


}, 10, 2);
```